# jquery ajax return part of data from process page

Tags: jquery

I want to send some orders from main page, then in process page, there would be a mysql query, query out many rows of data. But I want return these data into several `divs` in main page. I tried code here, but this will cause `Uncaught TypeError:` *(return data)*  `has no method 'find'`, So is it possible do this work in jquery.ajax and How? thanks.

---

Main page:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "precess", 
    dataType: "html",
    type: 'POST',
    data: "process="+code, 
    success: function(data){ 
        $("#title").html(data.find("#a1"));
        $("#content").html(data.find("#a2"));
    }
});

<div id="title"></div>
/* some other html codes */
<div id="content"></div>
```

---

Process page

```
<div id="a1">/* something from mysql query */</div>
<div id="a2">/* something from mysql query */</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct solution is posted already, but you should consider using json for this.

**Javascript**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "precess", 
    dataType: "html",
    type: 'POST',
    data: "process="+code, 
    success: function(json){
        var result = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
        $("#title").html(result.a1);
        $("#content").html(result.a2);
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
$result = array();
$result['a1'] = 'foo';
$result['a2'] = 'bar';
echo json_encode($result);
```